# URL with &gt at the end

Tags: regex, wordpress

I would like a rule in my htaccess file to do the following using regex:

- Replace a url like www.domain.com/something&gt
- With www.domain.com/something

i.e. get rid of this &gt that appears at the end of some urls!  ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can set and let me know if that not work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^www\.domain\.com/something>$ /www.domain.com/something? [R=301,L]
```

Thanks